# How to parse multiple JSON Objects received from servlet with AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, servlets, combobox

I know this has been asked to death, but my problem goes a bit different than the already available answers.

I wish to change the value of 2 other comboboxes on the change listener of first combobox. This was happening smoothly when there was just 1 combobox/dropdown. But now the separation or parsing of data is not happening for second combobox.

```
categoryValue = req.getParameter("bellCategorySel");

List<String> paramList = insightDbConn.getParametersList(categoryValue);                
List<String> testStationList = insightDbConn.getTestStationsFromTestRecords(categoryValue);

String parsedParamList = new Gson().toJson(paramList);
String parsedtestStationList = new Gson().toJson(testStationList);

PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("parameters", parsedParamList);
json.put("teststations", parsedtestStationList);
out.print(json);
```

This is my Servlet code at the backend. I have placed a change listener on 1st combobox that gives me category value. Based on this value i have been calling other set of values (I have verified, values are coming properly) that I mean to put in 2 other combo boxes.

When it was just one list, all was good. Now there are 2.

Below is my front end code that parses the information wih AJAX :

```
$("#bellCategorySel").change(function(e) {      
    $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            cache : false,
            data : {
                frmSubmit : 'ajax',
                bellCategorySel : document.getElementById("bellCategorySel").value,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            url : '/AnalysisPanel/gaussianbell',
            success : function(jsonResponse) {                      
                var arr = JSON.parse(jsonResponse.parameters),
                opts = '';
                   $.each(arr, function(key, val){
                       opts += '<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>';
                   });
                   $('#bellParameterSel').empty().append(opts)

                 var stations = JSON.parse(jsonResponse.teststations),  
                 stns = '';
                   $.each(stns, function(key, val){
                       stns += '<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>';
                   });
                   $('#testStation').empty().append(stns)
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
         return false;
});
```

Tried debugging with Chrome, but no ! all was fine. 
The value of first combobox changes but the second one **stays blank/null**. No idea why !

Please go easy on me I am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

It look like the Javascript variable `station` that you fill with the JSON data is not that what you iterate in the `each()` call:

```
             var stations = JSON.parse(jsonResponse.teststations),  
             stns = '';
               $.each(stns, function(key, val){
```

Fix it to:

```
               $.each(stations, function(key, val){
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Yes, thats a little mistake you pointed out. Also, I did some gimmick at back end too. I concatenated 2 strings in json array format and then at the front end i split them in two different arrays. And it worked :)